# Is it possible to make a Kafka Consumer override/ignore its configurations when doing a records poll?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer that should consume minimum `1MB` worth of records at each poll. This data is then written to file and stored partioned by date - in example, records consumed during 2022.09.22 should be written to a file and stored to the `date_id=20220922` folder. The file size should be a minimum of `1MB`.

The configuration properties `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` are tuned to get the desired behavior. The problem, though, arrives when a new day occurs. On a day change, the consumer should consume the remaining records on topic (it is less than `1MB`) without having to wait for the poll size threshold to be met or for the wait time to time out. The consumer should do a type of "force fetch" of the remaining records available on topic.

Is it possible to override the configuration of the consumer to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties are what they are - you cannot change them at runtime without stopping the consumer and creating a new one with other config settings.

Worth mentioning that the HDFS/S3 sink connectors from Confluent already have a Date directory partitions. They also work for local storage, but distributed storage makes more sense when your kafka consumers are distributed